# Cannot access CFADMIN any more

Tags: coldfusion, adobe, coldfusion-10, cfml

I cannot access the ColdFusion 10 CFAdmin area and when I do I get the following in my logs

```
You tried to access the ColdFusion Administrator from a disallowed IP address (123.456.789.1).
The ColdFusion Administrator can only be concurrently accessed from localhost and 2 more IP addresses. 
The specific sequence of files included or processed is: ........
```

The problem is that I am trying this on my own machine which has (for example here) the IP address of 123.456.789.1

I've tried restarting the services but I get the same error still?

Anyone seen this before?

**Some clarification for what I've tried. Let say my remote server has the 123.456.789.1**

1st attempt.
Restarted services and ensured I was the first person to try and access the CFAdmin area - No luck

2nd attempt
Used the "123.456.789.1" server as a SSH tunnel so my machines IP address would be the same as the servers when I tried to connect. Again restarted and got same error (in the logs)

3rd attempt (getting desperate)
Installed "elinks" (a text based browser) on the actual server. Again restarted and got same error (in the logs) when trying to log in.

Comment: Did someone recently apply IP Address restrictions to the ColdFusion administrator? You will only be able to access the administrator from one of those IP addresses. You should still be able to access from localhost.

Comment: I've added some more details as to why I can't do this.

Comment: Have you tried from the server itself? I see that you tried SSH but I'm not sure that is the same as from localhost (as far as ColdFusion admin is concerned).  Have you figured out why this security is kicking in yet? Did your license expire, did someone turn on IP restrictions, ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that the IP restriction to CF Admin is applied. Go to **Security > Allowed IP Addresses** in CF Admin and remove the IPs (if any) from `Allowed IP Addresses for ColdFusion Administrator access` section.

That should fix it.

Edit: Since you are unable to access CF Admin, try this. Take a backup of neo-security.xml at C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\lib. Open it with text editor and locate

```
<var name='allowedAdminIPList'><string>IP_Address</string></var>
```

Delete the IP listed there (IP_Address in example) and now it should look like

```
<var name='allowedAdminIPList'><string></string></var>
```

Save the file, restart ColdFusion Application Service and check CF Admin.

Comment: Nope, this did not solve my problem. Btw I am using a developer edition and have created 3 instances on IIS.

Comment: @YoosafAbdulla can you post a new question or provide more details?

Comment: @AnitKumar I tried your solution but did not resolve my issue. That is what i meant.

Comment: @YoosafAbdulla can you share the entries from coldfusion-out.log after, trying once again?

Answer (score 2):

Is this a full copy of ColdFusion server or just a developer edition?  The '2 more IP addresses' makes me think its a developer copy and you have it open in other places.

Comment: Should be full version ( its on a live site) and the site is still accessible.

But .. even if its not a full version how do I access the CFAdmin area to apply our licence again?